# How to estimate the percentage error using differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

R=k/r^2      where k=constant and r=radius of the wire

How can I estimate the percentage error in r, if I want to have the percentage error in R to be plus/minus 1%

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Differentiate $R$ wrt $r$, taking modulus and rearranging we get$$1\%=|dR|/R\times100\%=2k|dr|/r^3R\times100\%$$

Comment: You need to solve for $|dr|/r\times100\%$. Can you complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$R = \frac{k}{r^2}$$

$$\frac{dR}{dr} = \frac{-2k}{r^3}$$

$$\implies \left|\frac{dR}{R}\right| = \frac{2 dr}{r}$$